# Maximum number of edges in a simple graph?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I found that the maximum number of edges in a simple graph is equal to $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} i$$

Where $n =$ number of vertices.

For example in a simple graph with $6$ vertices, there can be at most $15$ edges.  If there were any more edges then $2$ edges would connect the same pair of vertices and thus would not be a simple graph.

Is this a known theorem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is called the size of a [complete graph on $n$ vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph#Properties).  You can also write it as ${n\choose 2}$ since you have $n$ points and any $2$ of them define an edge.